# Initialising enum via constructors

Tags: c++, class, function, constructor, enums

I have an enum as a public memebr of a class as follows"

```
class myClass
{
    public:
        enum myEnum
        {
            myEnum1,
            myEnum2
        };
};
```

I also declare a constructors, a public parameterized one as follows:

```
myClass(myEnum);
```

I define the same outside the classs definition as follows:

```
myClass :: myClass(myEnum E)
{
}
```

**How do I initialise myEnum with default arguments?**

I tried:

i)

```
myClass :: myClass(myEnum E = 0); //to int error
```

ii)

```
myClass :: myClass(myEnum E = {0}); //some error
```

iii)

```
myClass :: myClass(myEnum E = {0, 1}); //some error
```

**One thing I still don't seem to understand.**

How do I pass enum values to the constructor. I still get an error. And, I need to do it this way:

```
derived(arg1, arg2, arg3, enumHere, arg4, arg5); //call
```

Function definition:

```
derived(int a, int b, int c, enumHere, int 4, int 5) : base(a, b);
```

**Where am I supposed to initialise the enum, as one of the answers belowe do it?**

Comment: In my answer, I assumed it's c++, tags are not saying this, you could fix this, your question would gain much more attention then.

Comment: @Bartosz: It is indeed C++. Have changed the tags now. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems like you've mistaken type declaration with field. In your class `myEnum` is declaration of type, and class itself does not hold any field of that type.

Try this:

```
class myClass
{
    public:
        enum myEnum
        {
            myEnum1,
            myEnum2
        } enumField;
};
```

Then, your constructor should use member initialization:

```
myClass::myClass() : enumField(myEnum1) {};
```

If you want parametrized constructor:

```
myClass::myClass(myEnum e) : enumField(e) {};
```

If you want parametrized constructor with default argument:

```
myClass(myEnum e = myEnum1) : enumField(e) {};
```

If you want to use aforementioned constructor in derived class:

```
myDerived(myEnum e) : myClass(e) {};
```

Comment: Thanks. But, what if I used a constructor of the form:
derived(x, y, z) : base(x, y)? Where do I place the above then?

Comment: Added few cases in my answer.

Comment: Please note that single parameter constructor can be used to cast myEnum to myClass. Use explicit if thats not desirable.