# initializing enum with a constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, switch-statement, enum-class

I already found this really good explanation [Initialising enum via constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551523/initialising-enum-via-constructors) but it didn't fit my needs.

So I declare an enum inside a class and want to initialize it inside the class constructor and then call this enum via a switch statement inside a method but I'm not able to implement it.
Here is a code:

```
    class myClass {
        
        myClass();
        
        enum class State;

        void update();

        };
    
    
    //  initialise State() with default value, so state1=0, state2=1
    myClass::myClass() : State() {} 
    
    enum class
        myClass::State
        {
            state1,
            state2
        } enumState;
    
    
    
    
    void myClass::update(){
    
    switch (enumState){
    
    case enumState.state1:
         break;
    case enumState.state2:
         break;

    }
}
```

But obviously it is not the correct way to implement it.

I get these errors:

error: ‘enum class myClass::State’ is not a non-static data member of ‘myClass’

error: request for member ‘state1’ in ‘enumState’, which is of non-class type ‘myClass::State’

Can someone explain me how to implement such a code and what if I want to initialise State with default parameter ?

Thank you !

Comment: You cannot initialize a **type**, it is a compile-time construct. You want to do exactly what the [suggested answer does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12551625/7691729) - define a member variable and initialize that **object** in the constructor. Please create a [mcve], this is a mix of scattered declarations and definitions. E.g. `enumState` is a global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of your class you'll want to include a variable of type `State`:

```
class myClass {
    
    myClass();
     
    enum class State;

    // create a class member variable of type State named enumState;
    State enumState;

    void update();
};
```

Then inside of the constructor you can initialize the new `enumState` variable instead of the `State` enum type.

To resolve the second error you're seeing, you'll need to make to the `update()` method:

```
void myClass::update(){
    switch (enumState){
    case State::state1:
            break;
    case State::state2:
            break;
    
    }
}
```

This is due to the way enums values are accessed (using `Enum::value` rather than `enum.value`).